# Yii2 ActiveRecord with additional Where Clause

Tags: activerecord, yii2, rbac

I have a problem with RBAC adding additional "where" clause in my ActiveRecord query. How do I remove the Where Statement that contain the " Role = 'admin' "

FYI,

1. In my Model I do no have any override for the find()
2. I am using detkrium RBAC.
3. I do not have role column in the table (myrules). The SQL result is applicable to every user.

#### Error from the PHP

```
Database Exception – yii\db\Exception

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'role' in 'where clause'
The SQL being executed was: **SELECT * FROM `myrules` WHERE role NOT LIKE "admin" ORDER BY `seq_no` LIMIT 20**
Error Info: Array
(
[0] => 42S22
[1] => 1054
[2] => Unknown column 'role' in 'where clause
```

'

#### Model

```
namespace app\models;
use Yii;

class MyRulesModel extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
/**
* @inheritdoc
*/
public static function tableName()
{
return 'myrules';
}

......
}
```

#### Controller

```
use app\models\MyRulesModel;
use yii\data\Pagination;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\base\Model;



class Controller MyruleController extends \yii\web\Controller
{
public function actionMyrules()
{
$model = new MyRulesModel;


$query = MyRulesModel::find()->orderBy("seq_no ASC");

$dataprovider = new ActiveDataProvider(['query'=> $query ,
'pagination'=> ['pagesize'=>20]]);


echo $this->render('/network/myrules',['my_model'=>$dataprovider]); 
} 
}
```

Comment: The error is about the fact you don't have a column role in your table .. check if the table is properly formed and contain the columns you need ..

Answer (score 0):

Just to update.  I have found the problem.  Someone has changed the **/app/data/ActiveDataProvider.php** file.  Reverting to the original code fixed the problem.  Thanks.